# How to reduce or increase the size of a image in pixel level in c

Tags: c, bmp

The color data is just the color data, headers are not included. After I ran my code, the picture with new size shows only black pixel and at the bottom are some random dark colors. The size, width and height are all good but the colors.

```
//code to change to bigger image
int r, c, i, j;
for (r = 0; r < height; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < width*3; c++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    bigColorData[2*r+i][c] = oldColorData[r][c];
                }
                else
                {
                    bigColorData[2*r+i][2*c+2] = oldColorData[r][c];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're literally pixel-doubling a 24-bit color image, take a look at your `c` loop condition vs increment statement, and work out the array indexes in the inner loop by hand to see if they're doing what you expect.

Comment: How are you viewing the output. Are you creating a new bmp file? Also, the `i` and `j` loops should be removed. Just put four lines of code in the `c` loop to set the four pixels.

Comment: Please provide definitions of bigColorData and oldColorData. Also please show how are theese arrays initialised from/converted to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

From the `c < width*3` I deduce you are working with 3 bytes-per-pixel pixels (24 bit color).

But this will not work as the scanlines (width) are rounded up to the nearest word, so the loop must be:

```
int bits= 3*8;
int scanlinesize= ((bits + 31) / 32 * 4);
unsigned char *pix, *scanline= begin_of_image_data;

for (r = 0; r < height; r++, scanline += scanlinesize)
{
    pix= scanline;
    for (c = 0; c < width; c++, pix += 3)
    {
         // now pix points to the first byte of the pixel
```